# What is this symbol with designator T ? Looks like two pads pressed really close together

Tags: schematics, symbol

Are T1 and T2 relays?

[image]

This picture is grabbed from the datasheet of this component (high current power switch)

http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTS555-DS-v01_00-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30432ba3fa6f012bd3dfdd0b3b65

Answer (score 3):

T1 and T2 are MOSFETS.

As per the datasheet:

> Externally adjustable current limit If the device is conducting, the
>   sense current can be used to reduce the short circuit current and
>   allow higher lead inductance (see diagram above). The device will be
>   turned off, if the threshold voltage of T2 is reached by IS*RIS .
>   After a delay time defined by RV*CV T1 will be reset. The device is
>   turned on again, the short circuit current is defined by IL(SC) and
>   the device is shut down after td(SC) with latch function.

I am surprised Infineon used a poor symbol for a MOSFET right there...

Comment: The symbol used is conventionally used to draw the schematic within an integrated circuit. It is sometimes difficult to decide if a particular device is N or P channel when the functions include N, P and transmission configurations. This might help: http://web.ewu.edu/groups/technology/Claudio/ee430/Lectures/L3-print.pdf